# html5 Canvas to create a virtual room

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm seeking for something that can mix two images above each other to create a dynamic environment, see example below:
http://www.armstrong.com/flooring/design-a-room.asp?darScene=10&shortCode=&productCategory=

I was able to decode the method.
they mix those images for example:
http://www.armstrong.com/ei2/data/assets/Robbins/0557AW148630.jpg
http://www.armstrong.com/ei2/data/images/room-scenes/RSX3050L_2A.jpg

output: http://www.armstrong.com/ei2/cgi-bin/Swatchbox.cgi?a=RenderImage%5Boutput=jpegstream%5D&v=1&i=data/images/room-scenes/RSEWE5205_2&o=data/out/&w=530&h=4444&Floor=~stitch~data/assets/Robbins/0557AW148630~%5BSpecialStitch=randomOffset%5D%5BPPF=75%5D

this will be a part of an overall website experience which customers can customize. It feels like this requires backend scripting, though I would like to keep it to php/javascript/jquery if possible.

I found many solutions only, that requires the script to be executed on their side which requires a monthly fee. This is not an option to use anything remotely. Though paying for a product is an option if its capability is not limited on another server.

Comment: php is "backend scripting"

Comment: I know, but it is very limited thus uses perl packages. My aim is to make it as portable as possible

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you want to do something like that, you can go for some html5 canvas.

I've done something very similar, and I used JCanvas. http://calebevans.me/projects/jcanvas/index.php
the best part is the multiple layers, and the ability to change and control z-index in them.
That way you can layer different transparent pngs and even move them around.

Comment: it's in spanish, but ist easy to see. in the link below, do a search like "playa" spanish for beach. click on an image, and in the lightbox look for the tab that says "habitacion". there's my working canvas.
you can also use controls below to make changes.
http://mores.es/tienda_vinilos.php
good luck!